# $(element).position().top returning wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on asp.net project and recently we have upgraded jQuery version from 1.11.1 to 3.3.1 and then after we are facing some weird issue with:

```
$(element).position().top
```

Do you guys have any idea that we can use as an alternative to `position().top` or JavaScript?

I have also found some bugs posted regarding [position().top](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3984) returning wrong values in jQuery 3.3.1.

Can someone please suggest an alternative to `position().top`? It would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to delay the measure and see if it help.

Comment: [`position()`](https://api.jquery.com/position/) uses the margin box of the element relative to the padding box of its "offset parent". If you're used to the modern trend of measuring everything to the border box, that can appear incorrect. You can see this reflected in the response to the bug. They're actually fixing the previous behavior, which was wrong (over several versions, so really they're breaking a lot of code).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example to see how to get TOP property in plain JS:

```js
// Source: https://plainjs.com/javascript/styles/get-the-position-of-an-element-relative-to-the-document-24/
function offset(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
    scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
    scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    return { top: rect.top + scrollTop, left: rect.left + scrollLeft }
}


// Get properties
var test_element = document.getElementById('relative-div'),
    position = offset(test_element);


// Display them here
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(position, null, 2);


// Use property where you need it
console.log(position.top);
```

```css
#test{
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: red;
}
#relative-div{
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'>
  <div id='relative-div'>xxx</div>
</div>
<pre id='result'></pre>
```

As someone suggested, the wrong position value you receive may occur because of asynchronous functions that may influence the behavior and aspect of page.

Another possible reason might be that you need to wait for full page load, before reading that property. To do this use $(document).ready() as bellow:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     // here
     console.log($(element).position().top)
})
```

Comment: You're assuming quite a bit when using `getClientBoundingRect` in this way; it is not a suitable replacement for `position()`. Indeed, [looking at the source of `position()`] it uses `getClientBoundingRect` only for `position: fixed` elements](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/e743cbd28553267f955f71ea7248377915613fd9/src/offset.js#L125).

Comment: @HereticMonkey thank you for pointing that out. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `position()` is `offset()` in your case it would be 
it returns an object containing the top and the left properties.

example :

```
var offset = $(element).offset();
top = offset.top();
left = offset.left();
```

i have also had issues where position() and offset() returned different values, and i couldnt tell why, i feel its a bug in the jquery library, but just try this.. i hope this works.

Comment: [`offset()`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) is a different function precisely because it calculates a different value. That is, the element's position relative to the document rather than relative to the offset parent. It's not a bug.